# How to check for a class type and see if it implements an interface

Tags: java, oop

I have an arrayList with a number of different objects including `Log`, `Frog`, `Turtle`, `Rock` etc.
I would like to perform some action that only applies to the class types that implements and interface, `IAction`.

Is there something built in in Java that can do this?
My attempt:

```
for(Object o : objectList){
    if(o.getClass instanceof IAction){ // doesnt work
        // doWork
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You check the instance, not the class:

```
for (Object o : objectList){
    if (o instanceof IAction) { 
        // doWork
    }
}
```